# bring files in feature branch back under git-lfs

Tags: git, migrate, git-lfs

**Environment**

```
git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)
git-lfs/2.8.0 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.12.7)
```

```
$ more .gitattributes
**/data/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
**/results/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

**Issue**

The issue plagues one of my feature branches, where - unlike in master - some large files in a `data` folder are not tracked by lfs. This was due to cloning the repo, checking out to the feature branch and committing some changes before remembering to set up lfs to track large files again.

The master branch correctly has these files tracked by lfs, but when I checkout to the feature branch, I get:

```
Switched to branch 'feature'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature'.
Encountered 27 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't:
...
```

**Attempted fix**

This should be a pretty easy to fix problem, and it's indeed mentioned in the [tutorial](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#migrating-existing-repository-data-to-lfs) under

> **Migrating existing repository data to LFS**
>
> Sometimes files end up committed within your repository when they should have been committed with LFS...

My problem is that the solution proposed there doesn't seem to do anything:

```
$ git lfs migrate import --include="*/data/*" # same path as in .gitattributes
migrate: Fetching remote refs: ..., done
migrate: Sorting commits: ..., done
migrate: Rewriting commits: 100% (0/0), done
migrate: Updating refs: ..., done
migrate: checkout: ..., done
```

which as you can see, does absolutely nothing in terms of rewriting commits.

I figured out from other issues that this might be because these files have already been pushed to remote (right?). So I tried to use the `--no-rewrite` option, to avoid rewriting history and just importing these files under lfs as a new commit, but here's what I get:

```
$ git lfs migrate import --no-rewrite --include="*/data/*"
fatal: expected one or more files with --no-rewrite
```

Can anyone explain me this error? How on earth do I make sure that in sub-branch feature all files with a path matching `**/data/**` are again tracked by lfs (as prescribed by `.gitattributes`), as it's already the case in master? I cannot merge this feature branch until this is fixed.

**UPDATE**

I spotted the problem with the `--no-rewrite` attempt, which caused the `expected one or more files with --no-rewrite` error: the syntax is different when using this option, and one shouldn't use include.

Correcting for that now gives the following error, which I still haven't been able to figure out:

```
$ git lfs migrate import --no-rewrite "**/data/**"
fatal: no Git LFS filters found in .gitattributes
```

This doesn't seem the case to me, see my `.gitattributes` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You mention trying to do this without a rewrite; you could do that by checking out the offending branch, then

```
git rm --cached -r :/:
git add :/:
git commit
```

This will cause all files to be re-staged, which (as long as LFS is now set up correctly) will re-apply the clean filter that puts the large content into LFS and swaps in LFS pointer files.

**BUT** this means that the large files are still in your branch history, and will become part of `master` history when you merge.  This partially defeats the purpose of using LFS.

The only way to *really* fix this is to rewrite the history, which will require biting the bullet on coordinating a team-wide recovery to (essentially) an upstream rebase condition.

Comment: But how would that be done? Not by just removing `--no-rewrite`, cause then the command would be the first one I put in my post, which as I said, does nothing at all.

Comment: @kilgoretrout - as explained in the migrate docs, if you specify a ref (`--include-ref`) or say to migrate everything (`--everything`) then the specified history is imported / rewritten even if it exists on a remote (thus requiring a force push afterward).

Comment: You're right, I should have dug the docs a bit further. The scary part of your answer isn't there though - what do you mean that a "team-wide recovery" be needed afterwards? What steps do other team members need to take after I'll force push this change?

Comment: @kilgoretrout - The `git rebase` docs address the condition of an "upstream rebase"; all history rewrites are basically equivalent to this, so you should look over that section of the rebase docs or search for relevant SO q&a that go into detail about it; but tl;dr is, if you're doing a rewrite that touches a lot of refs, or that's specifically meant as a clean-up like this one, you might want to coordinate such that (1) everyone pushes everything and discards their clones (2) you clean up the origin (3) every re-clones

Comment: ok, then last question is: to ensure that `git lfs migrate import --everything` only acts on the filters that I specified in my .gitattributes, should I mix it with the `--fixup` option? I ask cause of the error I'm getting when using --no-rewrite (see update to the question).